# Specifying Unit Test Location in Gradle

Tags: scala, junit, gradle, scalatest

I've been getting my feet wet with Gradle for a school project (not an assignment) and I have this project that is divided into two folder, `src/main/scala` and `src/test/scala`.

As you can probably tell, the test folder stores my Unit Tests but for some reason I can't get Gradle to find them and tun them as it should. I'm using Scala with ScalaTest for this project.

Is there any way to tell Gradle where to look for test files? Or is there any logical explanation to why it isn't detecting my files?

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/scala']
        }
    }
    test {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['test/scala']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:2.1.+'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
    testLogging {
        // Show that tests are run in the command-line output
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are the standard locations.  If your tests aren't running, then something else must be wrong.  How do you know they aren't running?

Comment: The build test report is coming out empty.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but my Unit Tests are ScalaUnit.

Comment: What's ScalaUnit? Do you mean ScalaTest? Are you aware that Scala code needs to go into `src/main/scala` or `src/test/scala`, not `.../java`?

Comment: Yes, ScalaTest. No, I wasn't aware. Let me try this.

EDIT: I changed it, but still no luck. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [gradle scala plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html), you can change the location of the source and test directory by adding something like the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/scala']
        }
    }
    test {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['test/scala']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still isn't working. I have updated the main post wiht my build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the correct build.gradle to get it to work thanks to @ditkin 's reply. Turns out I needed to put the full `src/main/scala` and `src/test/scala`.

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/scala']
        }
    }
    test {
        scala {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/scala']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:2.1.+'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
    testLogging {
        // Show that tests are run in the command-line output
        events 'started', 'passed'
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole `sourceSets` block is redundant, as is `useJUnit()`. These are already the defaults.

Comment: Your problem was likely a different one, as these are literally the defaults.

Answer (score -1):

Look here for detailed explanation how test works and configure them http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test

Comment: Please try to explain What that link include as that link may be removed from the source in the future and then we cant access the information.